# Angular Parent to Child Data Sending

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How to send data on a button click event from parent to child ?

I was sending data from parent to child using a button click event but i unable to send

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you can send data from a parent component to a child component using property binding:

```js
// Parent component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [message]="message"></app-child>
    <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  message = 'Hello from parent';

  sendMessage() {
    this.message = 'Message sent from parent';
  }
}

// Child component
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() message: string;
}
```

ParentComponent has a property message that is bound to a message input in the ChildComponent using the square bracket syntax [message]. The ParentComponent also has a sendMessage method that changes the value of message when a button is clicked. The ChildComponent displays the value of message in its template. When the button is clicked, the message value is updated in the ParentComponent and automatically passed down to the ChildComponent through property binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in couple of ways:

1. use `@Input() someVariable` in the child component then

```html
<app-parent>
<app-child  [someVariable]="dataOnClickChange">    <app-child>
</app-parent>
```

that is good if the data on the click is changing.

2. use service and listen for changes/events. Just `subscribe` to it and in order to pass the click you can use `observable` or `behavioralSubject` with `next()`

More information on:

[data binding](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

[observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

[behavioralSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sharing-data-between-angular-components-parent-to-child?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

why you need to pass the click event to child component in the first place maybe there is a better way to accomplish what you need.